# polling database and scheduling job in angular js+struts project

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a web application. My requirement is I have to fetch data from database continuously (polling) and schedule the data to every 1 minute maybe using struts. How??

Answer (score 1):

Pooling continuously to the server on a fixed interval is not a very good approach. You should implement web sockets for this. To know more about web sockets you can check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

If you still want to implement this, you can try like following.

```
var PoolingController = function($scope, $timeout,$http){
     (function pool() {
     $http.get('<YOUR_API_URL>')
        .then(function(res) {
             //use res.data; 
             $timeout(pool, 60000);
        })
     })();
}
```